# zfs legacy mounts on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, zfs

I'm using zfs on a generic Ubuntu 18.04 system. Everything works fine when creating and mounting file systems using normal mountpoints.

However, I have a use case that would be helped if I could use legacy mounts that auto mount at boot time.

If I set my legacy mount as `noauto` and then manually mount after startup, everything works fine.

But when I remove `noauto`, I fail to automatically mount at boot. It's obvious what the problem is - during startup the attempt to mount the drive is taking place before the ZFS modules are loaded:

```
$ systemctl status home-vagrant.mount
● home-vagrant.mount - /home/vagrant
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-04-30 11:41:07 PDT; 24s ago
    Where: /home/vagrant
     What: vagrant
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 464 ExecMount=/bin/mount vagrant /home/vagrant -t zfs (code=exited, status=2)

Apr 30 11:41:07 ubuntu mount[464]: The ZFS modules are not loaded.
Apr 30 11:41:07 ubuntu mount[464]: Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them.
Apr 30 11:41:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: home-vagrant.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=2
Apr 30 11:41:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: home-vagrant.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 30 11:41:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to mount /home/vagrant.
```

Of course, later in the boot process the ZFS modules are loaded and it can be mounted properly. I can see the two events in the boot printout, it's pretty obvious what the problem is - but not the fix.

I haven't been able to find a simple how-to for dealing with this. From what I can see, it seems like installing zsh-initramfs is supposed to help with this - but how?

What little information is floating around out there seems to primarily deal with using zsh for the root file system, and in many cases that is a lot more complicated.

Part of the use case might clear up why I want legacy mounts - I have bind mounts that are being mounted in the ZFS file system. So a workaround would be to use links instead of mounts - and if I can't solve this problem that's what I'll do.

But it seems like this should be doable!

Comment: [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) question ?

Comment: @laupaulus Yes, AskUbuntu is not my first choice but I will go there.

Comment: what about using a systemd mount unit to require zfs?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to load zfs kernel modules in your initrd.
I'm not sure about Ubuntu, but on CentOS/Fedora, you could add a script to /etc/sysconfig/modules that executes *really* early on, as soon as the rootfs is mounted. You may want to look at whether there is an analogue in Ubuntu.